# The image of a given value in a relation

Tags: notation, relations

I have a relation $R$ given below:

$$R = \{(a,1), (a,2), (b,1)\}$$

To get the image set of a, we can write $R(|\{a\}|) = \{1,2\}$ in Z notation, using thick brackets symbol $(| |)$.

Is there a mathematical symbol to represent this rather than using the Z notation? Can we have $R(a)$ like what we usually do to get a function image of a given value, e.g. $f(a)$?

Comment: Yes [$f[A]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset). Thus $R[ \{ a \} ]= \{ 1,2 \}$

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA. Can we say that ```R(a) = R[{a}] = {1,2}```?

Comment: $R(a)$ is the value of $R$ for argument $a$. It is defined only for functions; in your case - being $R$ a relation which is **not** functional - we have two different "values" for argument $a$

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, I got your point. I was looking at this page [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Image_(Set_Theory)/Relation/Element) which says that R(s) is another way to write R[{s}] and I got confused.